port: command not found
I tried to install Clang 17 with the following command on my MacOS Sonoma:
sudo port install clang-17

but got the following error:
sudo: port: command not found

Tried
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH

but without a success.
How to fix this?

Did you install MacPorts? And if yes, to which path?

@nohillside Yes, it is it!

Did you add the path in /etc/paths.d ?

@nohillside now port command runs without additional paths and I successfully installed Clang-17, but can't figure out where is it. clang command still runs my Clang-15 from XCode.

The list of files clang-17 installs is here.

PATH doesn‘t get passed by sudo, to avoid security issues. To make sure port is accessible, add a file containing its path to /etc/paths.d.

finally got this to work, macOS uses zshrc instead of the usual rc conf files listed from the other posts.. hopefully this helps someone :-D
based my result on this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694395/sudo-port-command-not-found#18847280
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/local/bin"' >> ~/.zshrc 
echo 'export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/opt/local/share/info"' >> ~/.zshrc 
echo 'export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/opt/local/share/man"' >> ~/.zshrc


I sugest you read this section of the MacPorts guide- https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.shell.html
